# Ubuntu 20.04 loses network in AWS after updates 28 october

Tags: networking, apt, server, upgrade, amazon-ec2

28 october I run a series of normal updates on one of my Amazon-EC2 instances. For some reason it locked up and I had to reboot it. It got up but it never got any network again. So after a lot of troubleshooting I restored it from an old snapshot. After updating it (that went smoothly) I rebooted as expected and it got up, but without network connectivity. This is quite annoying.

Is this a known problem? When I look in dpkg.log in the instance that crashed first, the following packages were updated (filtered dump from dpkg.log). I see quite a lot of network-related stuff there.

**Edit 2:** I found the offending package by interval halving the updates from the old image. If I allow this update:

```
netplan.io/focal-updates 0.100-0ubuntu4~20.04.2 amd64 [upgradable from: 0.99-0ubuntu3~20.04.2]
```

the machine will not get up on the network again after a reboot. I should of course have suspected netplan all along but whatever. I get one error message in /var/log/dmsg that have note investigated enough but seems network-related:

```
[    3.396831] kernel: ena 0000:00:05.0: LLQ is not supported Fallback to host mode policy.
```

**Edit:** I have now looked at the first instance and it seems as if it does not help if I downgrade the packages (I do that on another instance using chroot). So I suspect (but very uncertain) that it is *just* a reboot issue although seemingly very difficult to solve.

```
upgrade ca-certificates:all 20190110ubuntu1.1 20201027ubuntu0.20.04.1
upgrade distro-info-data:all 0.43ubuntu1.1 0.43ubuntu1.2
upgrade accountsservice:amd64 0.6.55-0ubuntu12~20.04.1 0.6.55-0ubuntu12~20.04.2
upgrade libaccountsservice0:amd64 0.6.55-0ubuntu12~20.04.1 0.6.55-0ubuntu12~20.04.2
upgrade bind9-dnsutils:amd64 1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.3 1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.4
upgrade bind9-libs:amd64 1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.3 1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.4
upgrade bind9-host:amd64 1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.3 1:9.16.1-0ubuntu2.4
upgrade libplymouth5:amd64 0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6 0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.1
upgrade plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text:amd64 0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6 0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.1
upgrade plymouth:amd64 0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6 0.9.4git20200323-0ubuntu6.1
```

My (admittedly bad) forensics says that something goes wrong in cloud-init. That init is necessary as an instance gets a new IP every time it boots (it has a static IP but that is routed to the dynamic one).

I see two ways forward: Either I restore from my dump again and try to hold the packages above somehow or I find a way to fix the resulting network issue without having access to the live machine (as it has no network), I do have access to the file system when the machine is taken down though.

Any ideas or help appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: @heynnema: Thank you for the formatting. A lot more readable.

Comment: No problem. The way to format text like that is to: select the text and then click on the {} icon.

Comment: You edited your subject title... and it's too long... and the **edit** part belongs in the text of the body.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will help in your specific case, but I know it's helped a lot of other EC2 users with SSH problems.

Note: Change the MAC addresses in the example for your information...

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      match:
        macaddress: 06:bf:0c:4a:a5:d6
      set-name: eth0
  bridges:
    br0:
      dhcp4: true
      macaddress: 06:bf:0c:4a:a5:d6
      interfaces:
        - eth0
```

---

**Note**: You may need to create `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg`

```
network: {config: disabled}
```

---

`sudo netplan --debug generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot` # mandatory

See https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/faq.html

Comment: Good tips, but I have tried similar things, by removing or changing the macaddress entry (and adding the 99-disable file of course). That does not help with the network issue. The machine gets an IP4-address before cloud-init starts (dhclient says so in the syslog), but then cloud-init does it's magic and everything breaks.

I also have no way of running netplan on a live system as I only have access to the file system when I take the machine down. I have netplan apply as a cron job @boot. 

The reboot thing is easy though, that can be done from the system management in AWS (CLI or web).

Comment: @dakr Did you use the same MAC address in both places in the .yaml? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` (if it exists), and `sudo lshw -C network` both when it works and again when it fails. You shouldn't need a cron job. Have you looked at the bind configuration... esp since the update?

Comment: No, did not try that. /etc/network/interfaces does not exist.

Comment: No, did not try setting the mac at both places. The file `/etc/network/interfaces` does not exist. I have a hard time to run commands after it fails as it is quite unreachable then, the only way is to run a script that writes to a file. /etc/netplan/*.yaml now only contains the ethernets-subtree, no bridge-part. It works fine, but it will fail if I upgrade netplan. `lshw -C network` gives the expected information on a "Elastic Network Adapter (ENA)" from Amazon with all IPs and macs addresses expected.

Comment: Well... if you don't want to try my .yaml... and you don't want to show me requested information like `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `sudo lshw -C network`... I don't know how I'm supposed to help you.